# c fgets retrieves the whole array?

Tags: c, file, fgets, strlen

I have a file named phobebook where i retrieve the number of contacts I have(here the int is assigned on variable cc), then saved the names, address etc.
problem is when I display the info, the details are there but they are separated with new lines. I tried to put the \0 but it seems it does not work.

```
typedef struct myphonebook{
  char name[31];
  char address[101];
  char cellphone[11];
  char email[21];
} Myphonebooktype;

FILE*db;

db = fopen("db.txt", "r");

fscanf(db, "%d" , &cc);

pb = (Myphonebooktype*)malloc(cc*sizeof(Myphonebooktype));
addcounter = cc;

for(i = 0; i<cc ; i++){
  size_t lenn = strlen(pb[i].name);
  if (pb[i].name[lenn - 1] == '\n') {
    pb[i].name[lenn - 1] = '\0';
  }
  fgets(pb[i].name, sizeof(pb[i].name), db);

  size_t lena = strlen(pb[i].address);
  if (pb[i].address[lena - 1] == '\n') {
    pb[i].address[lena - 1] = '\0';
  }
  fgets(pb[i].address, sizeof(pb[i].address), db);

  size_t lenc = strlen(pb[i].cellphone);
  if (pb[i].cellphone[lenc - 1] == '\n') {
    pb[i].cellphone[lenc - 1] = '\0';
  }
  fgets(pb[i].cellphone, sizeof(pb[i].cellphone), db);

  size_t lene = strlen(pb[i].email);
  if (pb[i].email[lene - 1] == '\n') {
    pb[i].email[lene - 1] = '\0';
  }
  fgets(pb[i].email, sizeof(pb[i].email), db);
}
```

Comment: Try checking for `\r` also, i.e. replace with `\0` if you find `\n` or `\r`

Comment: 2 bruce wayne
mansion
88888888
batman@hero.com
john yeung
46 linggo
9393293226
my@yahoo.com my db.txt looks like this

Comment: @user3266210 Put that in the question, it's impossible to understand the exact structure in a comment.

Comment: if you are doing `lenn = strlen(pb[i].name)` then I suppose `pb[i].name[lenn - 1]` will always be `\0`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @unwind said, code is referencing uninitialized data before writing to it

```
  size_t lenn = strlen(pb[i].name);  // pb[i].name contents are not defined yet.
  ...
  fgets(pb[i].name, sizeof(pb[i].name), db);
```

Suggest creating a function to handle the reading of the line.

```
void ReadLine(FILE *db, char *dest, size_t size) {
  char buffer[size+2];
  dest[0] = '\0';
  if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, db) != NULL) {
    size_t len = strlen(buffer);
    // Get rid of potential \n
    if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n') buffer[--len] = '\0';
    strncpy(dest, buffer, size);
  }
} 


for(i = 0; i<cc ; i++) {
  ReadLine(db, pb[i].name, sizeof pb[i].name);
  ReadLine(db, pb[i].address, sizeof pb[i].address);
  ReadLine(db, pb[i].cellphone, sizeof pb[i].cellphone);
  ReadLine(db, pb[i].email, sizeof pb[i].email);
}
```

Additions could be made to `ReadLine()` to return EOF on NULL read, excessively long lines or `\r` concern as raised by @MadHatter.  It's all in one function, so easier to maintain and enhance code.

Comment: sorry for this noob question, should i fgets first and then use this readline function?

Comment: @user3266210 No, `fgets()` in incorporated in `ReadLine()`.

Comment: ok...but where is my dp (the File*dp), should i replace the stdin in the Readline() with dp?

Comment: wow that worked, it's like magic : ) tnx. it even solved my problem of not retrieving one contact's email add.  i'll study your function later. PS.anyway for people who will refer to this question, the file pointer is not dp but db. sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

You can't reference data in the newly allocated array of `Myphonebooktype` *before* initializing it. You calls to `strlen()` all generate undefined behavior, since the struct members haven't been initialized.

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).